# Generate javadoc with no javascript

Tags: javadoc

I want to generate javadoc with no javascript. I need to **display that in a html engine that does not support Javascript**.

It might be acceptable to generate the JAVADOC to another format like PDF, ODT, DOCX, etc.

I am using javadoc from:
openjdk version "9-Ubuntu"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode)